# How make hover selected when in corresponding page

Tags: css, hover

I would like to set the hover active when user in the corresponding page. For example when user in HOME it will make the hover active. The default icon is white colour when in corresponding page it will become green colour.

This is the my origianl source from jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kQNHj/

Here is my basic html source code

```
<div class="submenu">
    <div class="submenu-img" >        
        <a href="#"><div class="icon-home"></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="icon-groups"></div></a>
        <a href="#"><div class="icon-members"></div></a>                 
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my css

```
.submenu {
    background-color: #353535;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.submenu-img {       
    float: left;
    position: relative;    
    padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
    margin-left: 35%;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
    Submenu "Home" icon
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.submenu-img .icon-home {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img607/9549/j3oe.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 56px;
    width: 41px;
    margin: 0 55px 0 0;
    float:left;
}

.submenu-img .icon-home:hover {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img202/4181/nlnf.png);    
}

.submenu-img .icon-home:active {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img607/9549/j3oe.png);   
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
    Submenu "Groups" icon
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.submenu-img .icon-groups {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img191/1220/9sb7.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;    
    height: 54px;
    width: 49px;
    margin: 0 55px 0 0;
    float: left;

}

.submenu-img .icon-groups:hover {
   background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img818/6343/3vhv.png); 
}

.submenu-img .icon-groups:active {     
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img191/1220/9sb7.png);
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
    Submenu "Members" icon
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.submenu-img .icon-members {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img62/4964/6spa.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;    
    height: 54px;
    width: 64px;
    margin: 0 55px 0 0;
    float: left;
}

.submenu-img .icon-members:hover {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img842/6206/reko.png);
}

.submenu-img .icon-members:active {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img62/4964/6spa.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a "active" class to the icon when on corresponding page? Add 'active' to home icon when on home page, 'active' to groups icon when on groups page, etc.

I've edited the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: I try to add 'active' on my home-icon class but when i'm in the corresponding page it didn't hover the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do it like this if u are building a single page site
HTML
<a href="#"><div class="icon-home clickable"></div></a>

JS: add a lissener to the buttons with clickable class
$(function() {
  $(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");// add this class dynamically
  });
});

CSS
.active {
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img62/4964/6spa.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way do do that was proposed by David Pucko. If you have the possibility to change the template that generates your html - simply add a class of `active` to the needed icon (or preferably - a link) on page load. In order for it to look like *hovered* you need to change your css like this:

```
.submenu-img .icon-groups.active {     
    background-image: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img191/1220/9sb7.png);
}
```

Pay attention that I used a **dot**, not a **colon**. It's a mistake to use `:active`.

If you can't tweak the template - the only way to highlight the current icon will be by jQuery. Or it can rewritten it in vanilla JS if you want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current_url = window.location.href,
        top_menu_links = $('.submenu-img').children('a');

    switch (current_url) {
        case 'http://site.com/groups' :
        top_menu_links.eq(1).addClass('active');
        break;
      case label2:
        case 'http://site.com/members' :
        top_menu_links.eq(2).addClass('active');
        break;
      default:
        case 'http://site.com/' :
        top_menu_links.eq(0).addClass('active');
        break;
    }
});
```

Pay attention that the numbers used in the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) start from *zero*, not from *one*.

And again. In order for it to work you will need to add the css style for the icons with a class of `active` (see above in my answer).

Note: I cannot give you a live example on jsfiddle or any other online service but it should work.

Comment: Try this method on my site but it hover all the images.